# uploading an image to AWS using react-native-aws-signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I am try to upload an image to Amazon-s3 using react-native-aws-signature, here is my sample code i am attaching

```
var AWSSignature = require('react-native-aws-signature');
var awsSignature = new AWSSignature();
var source1 = {uri: response.uri, isStatic: true}; // this is uris which got from image picker
        console.log("source:"+JSON.stringify(source1));
        var credentials = {
          SecretKey: ‘security-key’,
          AccessKeyId: ‘AccesskeyId’,
          Bucket:’Bucket_name’
        };
        var options = {
          path: '/?Param2=value2&Param1=value1',
            method: 'POST',
            service: 'service',
            headers: {
                'X-Amz-Date': '20150209T123600Z',
                'host': 'xxxxx.aws.amazon.com'
            },
          region: ‘us-east-1,
          body: response.uri,
          credentials
        };
        awsSignature.setParams(options);
        var signature = awsSignature.getSignature();
        var authorization = awsSignature.getAuthorizationHeader();
```

here i am declaring the source1 in that response.uri is passing in body which is coming from image picker,Can any one give suggestions that is there any wrong in my code, if there please tell me that how to resolve it,Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hi, Same problem here. Found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can also leverage the new AWS Amplify library on the official AWS repo here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

This has a storage module for signing requests to S3: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/storage_guide.md

For React Native you'll need to install that:

```
npm install aws-amplify-react-native
```

If you're using Cognito User Pool credentials you'll need to link the native bridge as outlined here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development

Answer (score 0):

`awsSignature.getAuthorizationHeader();` will return the authorization header when given the correct parameters, and that's all it does.Just a step in the whole process of making a signed call to AWS API.

When sending POST request to S3, here is a link to the official documentation that you should read. [S3 Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html)
It seems you need to send in the image as a form parameter.